# C: How to store a string in a structure

Tags: c, string, struct

So I have a structure, and one of its members is a string.

```
struct Output {
     char *axis;
     int value;
};
struct Output Jsoutput;
```

My question is, how do I store a string in axis?

```
char whichaxis[4][3] = {"LX","LY","RY","RX"};
// Store which  axis and value of the joystick position in Jsoutput
Jsoutput.axis =  whichaxis[jse.number];
printf("%s\n",Jsoutput.axis);
```

I feel like there should be some `&` somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: What is `whichaxis`'s lifetime? Is it really on the stack like that? Are you planning on writing to the string at `axis`?

Comment: It's an event processing thing, so `Jsoutput.axis` will be overwritten regularly with a new pair of characters from `whichaxis`. `whichaxis` will not change, and should stay establsihed.

Comment: So you'll be reassigning `axis`, but never writing, e.g. `Jsoutput.axis[1] = 'x'`?

Comment: Oh ok, sorry misunderstood. In my main loop stuff happens if `Jsoutput.axis == "LX"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use strdup

```
Jsoutput.axis =  strdup(whichaxis[jse.number]);
```

Comment: Does this negate the need for malloc?

Comment: Yes strdup does a malloc.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a String with the function `strcpy(destination, source)`from `string.h`

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

```
Jsoutput.axis =  malloc(3);
strcpy(Jsoutput.axis,whichaxis[jse.number]);
```

Comment: And write all over who knows what, as there's no memory there to write to.

Comment: Better, but you need an extra byte for the `'\0'`, and you shouldn't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @Kevin What do you mean "cast the result of malloc"?

Comment: he means (char*) thats a cast

Comment: i dont know because in the refference they use a cast too

Comment: @theoB610 the proper answer depends on what exactly you intend to do with `whichaxis` and `axis`. See my comment on the question.

Comment: [You should not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/900873) cast in c. In c++ you should use `new` instead (though if you use malloc you must cast). (cc @theoB610)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "store" the string a second time.

```
char whichaxis[4][3] = {"LX","LY","RY","RX"};
```

Stores the string.

```
char *axis;
```

Says "I'm going to point at a string".

If you wanted a `&` in there, you could do:

```
Jsoutput.axis =  & (whichaxis[jse.number][0]) ;
```

But the original designers of C were very pragmatic and let arrays turn into pointers all the time for convenience.  See [What is array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) for more details.

Comment: Me saying I feel like there should be an & was just what I thought the solution would be.